# Erroneous pipeline: could not parse caps "video/x-raw-yuv,width=128,height=96,format=(fourcc)UYVY"

Tags: gstreamer

Following tutorial of original page in [Network Streaming](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html?gi-language=c)

There is the command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src  \
! video/x-raw-yuv,width=128,height=96,format='(fourcc)'UYVY \
! videoconvert ! ffenc_h263 ! video/x-h263 ! rtph263ppay pt=96 \
! udpsink host=192.168.1.1 port=5000 sync=false
```

Resulting:

```
(gst-launch-1.0:2616): GStreamer-WARNING **: 10:02:12.327: 0.10-style raw video caps are being created. Should be video/x-raw,format=(string).. now.
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not parse caps "video/x-raw-yuv,width=128,height=96,format=(fourcc)UYVY"
```

And command doesn't get executed. Anyone knows why it doesn't get executed?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, caps are provided as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src  \
! video/x-raw-yuv, width=128, height=96,format=UYVY \
! fakesink
```

Debug using a small pipeline; adding one element at a time and terminating it with fakesink.